# UITextView - InsertText doesn't auto-correct or auto-capitalize

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, uitextview

I have a custom `InputView` on a `UITextView` with auto-correct and auto-capitalization turned on.

My custom input view has a bunch of `UIButtons` that call `InsertText` on the `UITextView`. This works fine for inserting text at the current cursor position. The problem is that auto-correction and auto-capitalization do not work when `InsertText` is called. If input comes in through a bluetooth keyboard, or the standard keyboard, everything works fine.

Is there some method I can call on `UITextView` to invalidate auto-correct/auto-capitalization? `SetNeedsDisplay` was my first attempt, but it had no effect. Also, my app may potentially be iOS 7 and higher, so it's fine to use newer text APIs.

*NOTE: I'm using MonoTouch (Xamarin.iOS), but Objective-C answers are welcome.

Comment: This is a long shot, but if you could simulate key press events you could reproduce the text you want to insert. It's not a very elegant solution though.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd love to do. Which APIs can allow me to do this?

Comment: I found the following article. But I am afraid that the app would get rejected by Apple. http://blog.lazerwalker.com/blog/2013/10/17/more-fun-with-simulated-ios-events-keypresses

Comment: Sadly, I'm looking for an App Store approved option... Can't use private APIs.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Please give us an update if you find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a way in which this works:

- Implement your own `NSTextStorage`
- Setup an `NSLayoutManager` and `NSTextContainer` to coordinate your `NSTextStorage` with `UITextView`
- When programmatically modifying your `NSTextStorage` subclass, auto correct "just works"

I think this works because modifying `NSTextStorage` fires events that notify the `UITextView` to update things like autocorrect. It works only on iOS 7 and higher.

Comment: I'd like more details about this answer :) Can you post demo code?

Comment: I've followed all of the steps and I am appending `NSAttributedString` to the NSTextStorage in order, @"t", @"e", @"s", @"t", @"t", @" " and sending it through NSTextContainer to UITextView and the UITextView is updated to say "t" --> "te" --> "tes" --> "test" --> "testt" --> "testt " And the whole time there is never any auto correction. ?

Comment: Are you calling insertText on the UITextView? I checked our app and that is what ours is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Not without rolling your own autocorrect system. The iOS autocorrect system is opaque to developers, and only works on keyboard input. Any time you explicitly set the `.text` property on an input or text view, the value you set is what will appear.

Comment: What is the recommended method to implement your own `inputView`? Just call `insertText`, and auto-correct doesn't work? In my case I'm replacing the system keyboard with a custom one.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yeah, I'm unsure about the best way to go about that. Good luck :)